# Wireless connection not functioning in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I've read lots of similar posts on this topic and none of them seem to work out for me.

I have an HP pavilion series laptop and dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. After installation, everything worked fine except the Wi-Fi connection. It is responding to Ethernet connectivity but Wireless connection options aren't popping up at all. I'm a newbie at this. Please help me out.

Details about my adapter are

[image]

Comment: please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1037395/edit) your question and copy-paste the output of the terminal rather than posting an image

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.